# Android FragmentDialog and interfaces, how to know what button executed the dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a DatePicker Dialog Fragment to use into my Fragments.

I have two buttons in my fragment. Each button click I get a date.

In listener result of my fragment,I need to know what button was clicked to execute an action, since I have two buttons that can call the dialogFragment.

How could I know which button was clicked at  onCalendarDialogDateSelected result event?

In my Fragment, I do:

```
public class AgendaMedFragment extends Fragment implements CalendarDialogFragment.CalendarDialogListener {
    .....

    Button but_data_de= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.but_data_agenda_de);
    but_data_de.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            CalendarDialogFragment myDialogFragment = CalendarDialogFragment
                    .newInstance(year,month,day);
            myDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(AgendaMedFragment.this,0);
            myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialogFragment");
        }
    });

    Button but_data_para= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.but_data_agenda_para);
    but_data_para.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            CalendarDialogFragment myDialogFragment = CalendarDialogFragment
                    .newInstance(year,month,day);
            myDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(AgendaMedFragment.this,0);
            myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialogFragment");
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void onCalendarDialogDateSelected(int year, int month, int day) {
        //Here I need to know what button was clicked to execute an action, since I have two buttons that can call the dialogFragment
    }
}
```

and my dialogFragment is:

```
public class CalendarDialogFragment extends DialogFragment  implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    public interface CalendarDialogListener {
        void onCalendarDialogDateSelected(int year, int month, int day);
    }

    // Usa essa instância da interface para entregar eventos de ação
    CalendarDialogListener mListener;

    static CalendarDialogFragment newInstance(int year, int month, int day) {
        CalendarDialogFragment dialog = new CalendarDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("year", year);
        args.putInt("month", month);
        args.putInt("day", day);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            mListener = (CalendarDialogListener) getTargetFragment();

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Calling Fragment must implement CalendarDialogListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int year = getArguments().getInt("year");
        int month = getArguments().getInt("month");
        int day= getArguments().getInt("day");
        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        Dialog myDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        return myDialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        mListener.onCalendarDialogDateSelected(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send one more argument to the constructor of DialogFragment, that corresponds to the button which is clicked.

Example :
if it is button1, send this as another argument to the dialogFragment constructor and use it in your code.

Comment: OK, But do I need modify the constructor to accept other argument? How to do it with a generic constructor

Comment: the newInstance method you have should be modifed in order to accept one more argument.

Comment: arg.putInt("button",0) - put 0 for one button and 1 for other. The bundle has all the arguments. You can increase more arguments in the bundle. Hope it helps.

Comment: OK, I can override it, but is there a way to make it generic

Comment: Could I pass a View to constructor?

Comment: Why you want to pass a view? If you want to know about the activity attached with fragment you can always get it through getActivity().

Comment: I want to pass a View to indicate what button was clicked and in  onListener  try know what button I used to?

Comment: You can pass view as an object to the fragment but am unable to understand how will you find out which button was clicked.

Comment: I did it:
    public void setCustomObjectListener(CalendarDialogListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }......... Next I used: myDialogFragment.setCustomObjectListener(new CalendarDialogFragment.CalendarDialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCalendarDialogDateSelected(int year, int month, int day) {
///
                    }
                });  Is this ok?